# Download directory tarball from Sourceforge

Tags: sourceforge

I'd like to download a number of files from Sourceforge.

Specifically, I want to download all files from http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.51.0/ or better, download all files matching a certain regexp.

Can you help me?